# NextJs + Mongoose + Mongo Atlas multiple connections even with caching

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, database-connection, mongodb-atlas

I am using NextJS to build an app. I am using MongoDB via mongoosejs to connect to my database hosted in mongoAtlas.

My database connection file looks like below

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const MONGO_URI =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? process.env.MONGO_URI_DEVELOPMENT
    : process.env.MONGO_URI_PRODUCTION;

console.log(`Connecting to ${MONGO_URI}`);

const database_connection = async () => {
  if (global.connection?.isConnected) {
    console.log("reusing database connection")
    return;
  }

  const database = await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
    authSource: "admin",
    useNewUrlParser: true
  });

  global.connection = { isConnected: database.connections[0].readyState }
  console.log("new database connection created")
  
};

export default database_connection;
```

I have seen this [MongoDB developer community thread](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/next-js-issue-with-multiple-unclosed-connections/10003) and this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12229).

The problem seems to happen only in dev mode(when you run `yarn run dev`). In the production version hosted on Vercel there seems to be no issue. I understand that in dev mode the server is restarted every time a change is saved so to cache a connection you need to use as global variable. As you can see above, I have done exactly that. The server even logs: `reusing database connection`, then in mongoAtlas it shows like 10 more connections opened.

How can I solve this issue or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find and solution for this? I am also facing for quite a month

Comment: The solution provided works for the production environment, for the development environment I just switch off and switch on the server on local host.

Comment: Can you share how you are starting the database connection? Like in your api files how do you initiate the connection?

Comment: Here is the guide I used to create my database connection: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nextjs-with-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and will update you, is it possible we can connect on skype or google meet or whatsapp?

Comment: Yes, I do not mind. Whats-app/ google meet works for me.

Comment: That's so kind of you, how to message you on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes, yes. When you are ready you can reach out here and we can plan the call.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to connect to database in with mongoose in Next.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.DB_URL

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose
    })
  }

  try {
    cached.conn = await cached.promise
  } catch (e) {
    cached.promise = null
    throw e
  }

  return cached.conn
}

export default dbConnect
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but same output